# NumPy: how to check leading dimension of non-owned array?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

In NumPy, one can have arrays which are just pointing towards data that was allocated in a different array in order to avoid deep copies. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ones((3,4))
b = a[:2]
```

Now `b` just contains a pointer to the array in `a`, as evidenced by the flags:

```py
b.flags
```

```
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

This is all fine as long as one is sticking to NumPy's operations, but now suppose that I have a function that accepts a 2-d array and passes it to some C function, which will index it like this: `(i,j) = j + i*ncol` (for row-major) or `(i,j) = i + j*nrow` (for column-major).

If I now try this:

```
c = a[:2,:2]
```

Now the leading dimension of the array will not match with the number of columns, so it cannot be indexed like that anymore.

How can I get the leading dimension of an array?

Examples:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.ascontiguousarray(np.ones((3,4)))
b = np.asfortranarray(a)
c = a[:2,:2] ### LDA is 4
d = b[:2,:2] ### LDA is 3
```